# Valid special character ↂ as variable name - error on Safari/iOS

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am using the special character ↂ as a JS variable name to namespace my framework. It should be valid according to the specs of both ES5 and ES6 (it is in the Unicode group '*Number, Letter*' (http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nl/list.htm))

On iOS Safari however this gives the error: `SyntaxError: Invalid character '\u8578'`. Which seems strange because that character code appears to be a Chinese character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/8578/index.htm

So the code snippet below does not work on iOS Safari (Have not tested desktop Safari)

```html
<script>
  var ↂ = 5;
  alert(ↂ);
</script>
```

I was trying around by setting a few values for `charset="..."` on the script tag but that didn't help

1. Why does iOS Safari not accept ↂ which should be valid even in ES5?
2. Is there a way to use ↂ without getting the error?

---

*Please do not respond with unasked advice like 'It is bad practice to use special characters in JS'. I am aware of your opinions, please keep them to yourselves*

Comment: Whats the encoding HTTP header you're sending with the HTML document that the script tag is inside?  Is there a "charset" meta header?

Comment: yes <meta charset="utf-8">

Comment: And the behavior is the same with a response header with GZIP encoding and without GZIP

Comment: Also fails on desktop Safari.

Comment: So you don't want the advice *"don't do it"*,  then what's up as an answer ? Would "*It's a bug in this browser, they really should follow the specs but if all the browsers did follow the specs 4/5 web dev would be without a job tomorrow, so we can't really blame them...*" would be an answer to you ? Or "*It's a bug, make your voice in their bug tracker (btw good luck stating that this is more important than any missing HTML5 API)*" be more appropriate ? Ps: you can always use `window['ↂ']` but I guess you won't like it either.

Comment: Yes Kaiido those are valid answers, thanks. However I cannot conclude from your way of speaking that your answers are hypothetical or that they are actually the case. 
What I was hoping to hear was that it was possible to use this symbol by for instance changing the charset of the document or script tags. And if this wasn't possible, get a list of symbols that Safari does support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer my own question. Apparently not all modern browsers follow the specifications of ES5/ES6 for allowed characters. I wrote a useful code snippet that will show you which variable names work in the **current** browser:

```js
var allowed = '';

function check() {
  var char = String.fromCharCode(i);
  if (char.length) {
    try {
      eval("var " + char + "=1;");
      allowed += char + ' ';
    } catch (e) {}
  }
}
for (var i = 0; i <= 15000; i++) {
  check(i);
}
document.body.innerHTML = allowed;
```

Also on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9539cc7q/

Raise the max char code (now 15000) to your liking, the code will then run longer

When run on Safari we can indeed see that the ↂ symbol is not allowed.